# How do I embed YouTube video that will work support keyboard in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, keyboard, accessibility, youtube

I'm looking for a way to embed youtube/flash video to html page that will work in firefox using only keyboard support.

The problem is that in FF you can't set the focus in/out of the player using your keyboard. You must use the mouse (Not Accessible).

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at two different approaches:

(1) Provide DHTML controls for the player, and just use Flash to render the video itself (I recommend this approach). See for example:

http://icant.co.uk/easy-youtube/

(2) Use JS to try and fix Flash focus issues:

http://blogs.adobe.com/accessibility/2009/04/firefox_focus_and_actual_links_1.html

I don't know if the Google Flash component exposes the required API hooks for that.